# How to get window title information from cmd in wmic?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, wmic

I know that you can get window title with:

```
tasklist /v
```

or

```
tasklist /v /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Untitled - Notepad"
```

Can I get something like that in wmic? I can't find any information about that.

Comment: Why do you want to use `wmic`? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Use powershell `Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTItle} |format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle –AutoSize`

Comment: If possible I don't want to run tasklist just to get window titles when I can get all other information in wmic.

Comment: Like I said, it is not possible.

Comment: It is possible do this by using some like this [answer (bat/+/C#)](https://superuser.com/a/1527244/969781), but not by using wmic, instead, this will generating an executable file and call/use it in your bat...
interested?