# Is there a Windows CMD command for pasting

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

If I have a file in the clipboard I can paste it to a directory using ctrl+v or right click + paste. Is there a way to execute the paste through command line?

Comment: What exactly do you want to execute through the command line?  How is right mouse click not executing a paste?

Comment: I want to execute a paste command through MATLAB using a system command

Comment: So you want to take the contents of the clipboard and execute a paste command thus creating a file?

Comment: Yes, I can do this in VBA as CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(CVar(DestinationFolder)).self.InvokeVerb "Paste"

Comment: I'm trying to do the same through MATLAB objShell = actxserver('shell.application'); objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(DestinationFolder); objFolderItem = objFolder.Self; but 'Self' is not recognised

Comment: See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/printclipexe-prints-any-text-or.html to paste text or filenames.

Comment: so, you need paste command line? not files? are this about "strings"?

Answer (score 2):

> - **Option #1**

Why not at the **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[commandline](/questions/tagged/commandline)** to run the **one-line**  **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** **command** to do this...

1) Copy **one** or **more** files to **ClipBoard**

2) Set **destination drive\folder:** `Copy-Item -Destination D:\Folder_Target`

- For paste your file in **`%temp%`** folder:

```PowerShell
powershell --NoProfile -command "Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList | Copy-Item -Destination $env:temp"

powershell --NoProfile -command "Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList | Copy-Item -Destination $env:temp"
```

- Or using alias

```PowerShell
powershell -nOp -c "gcb -Format FileDropList | cpi -Destination $env:temp -PassThru"
```

---

> - **Option #2**

- You can also do this with the **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** paste code in a hybrid **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** and **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** file.

Where **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** with **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** paste the code, it will be compiled and executed at run time.

- Usage:  **`paste.bat D:\folder\target\`**

```PowerShell
/* & @cls & @echo off & title <nul & title %~nx0: Past File to: "%~1" & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

2>nul >nul del /q /f "%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" & for /f tokens^=* %%c in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET" csc.exe
')do "%%~c" /t:exe /out:"%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" "%~f0" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo && goto :next

echo/Error: Check/edit ccs.exe command line/flags^!! && endlocal && goto :EOF

:next 
"%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" "%~1" & del /q /f "%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" & endlocal & goto :EOF && rem./ 2>nul >nul */

// C# code by @Andy Brown  https://www.experts-exchange.com/
// 
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TSPaste2
{
    class Program
    {
        //Getting destination foler :: note: from argument %~1 ::
        String[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        [STAThread] static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Setting Destination foler:
            string DestFolder = args[0];

            if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
            {
                //copy to D:\test ( note: note: C# args[0] == bat/cmd == "%~1" )
                foreach (string source in Clipboard.GetFileDropList())
                {
                    string Dest = DestFolder + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(source);
                     File.Copy(source, Dest, true); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- This is the **command line** used to **compile** the **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code:

```PowerShell
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe out:"%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" "%tmp%\TSPaste2.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o nologo
```

- This **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code was **compiled/tested** on **`csc.exe`** versions:

```PowerShell
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

- This is the **`command line`** used to **compile** the **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code:

```PowerShell
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /t:exe /out:"%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" "%tmp%\TSPaste2.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo
```

- **Usage**:  **`TSPaste2.exe C:\destination\folder`**

To keep the `TSPaste2.exe` compiled file, edit the code by adding this `line in bold/italics:`

```PowerShell
:next
copy /y "%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" "c:\some\folder"
"%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" "%~1" & del /q /f "%tmp%\TSPaste2.exe" & endlocal & goto :EOF && rem./ 2>nul >nul */
```

**Obs.: 1)** **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code /by **[@Andy Brown / Experts-Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/members/AndrewDBrown.html)** **[C Paste files from clipboard](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29067991/C-Paste-files-from-clipboard.html)**

**Obs.: 2)** **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code **overwrites** files, if they exist in the destination folder.

Read more: **[File.Copy Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8)**

Answer (score 0):

Below are steps on how to copy a single file from one directory to another directory.

**Copying a single file**

Using the cd command, move to the directory that contains the file you want to copy.

Type a command similar to the following command.

```
copy myfile.txt c:\my\location
```

In the example above, you would substitute "myfile.txt" with the name of the file you want to copy, and "c:\my\location" with the destination directory. To see files available in the current directory use the dir command.

**Copying multiple files to another location**

Below are the steps on how to copy multiple files from one directory to another directory.

Using the cd command, move to the directory that contains the files you want to copy.

Once in the directory that contains the files you want to copy, type a command similar to one of the following commands.

```
copy *.* c:\mydir
```

In the example above, the command would copy every file in the current directory to the "mydir" directory.

```
copy *.txt c:\mydir
```

In the example above, the command would copy every txt, or text file, in the current directory into the "mydir" directory.

Source: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000766.htm